# Podcasts showing twice in the "My Podcasts tab" on iTunes

Tags: itunes, podcasts

In the "My Podcasts" tab, almost every podcast of mine is appearing twice at the left column like this:

[image]

However, in the `Episode List` display mode, everything is just fine:

[image]

Is there any way I can get it fixed for the `Podcasts` display mode so that every podcast only shows up once?

For the record I'm using 12.3.2 (the latest version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A day later it managed to fix itself. Looks like the problem may be caused by some cache that is cleared when reboot.